# 'Cannot set property of undefined' error when applying bindings

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, typescript

So I am getting the console error `Cannot set property 'stepModels' of undefined` but the typescript compiles fine. What am I doing wrong here? I can't seem to figure out. Any help is much appreciated.

```
class ViewModel {

    public index: number;
    public percentage: number;
    public getTemplate: any;
    public goNext: any;
    public goPrevious: any;
    public stepModels: KnockoutObservable<Array<Step>>;
    public currentStep: KnockoutObservable<Step>;
    public currentIndex: KnockoutComputed<number>;
    public currentPercentage: KnockoutComputed<number>;
    public canGoNext: KnockoutComputed<boolean>;
    public canGoPrevious: KnockoutComputed<boolean>;

    constructor() {
        let self = this;

        self.stepModels = ko.observableArray([
            new Step(1, 'emailTmpl'),
            new Step(2, 'usernameTmpl'),
            new Step(3, 'passwordTmpl'),
            new Step(4, 'questionsMainTmpl'),
            new Step(5, 'questionsTmpl'),
            new Step(6, 'questionsFinalTmpl'),
            new Step(7, 'verifyTmpl'),
            new Step(8, 'successTmpl')
        ]);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
ko.applyBindings(ViewModel, element);
```

Comment: It seems that you don't initialize `stepModels` property.

Comment: How do you instantiate this view model?

Comment: @Alex `ko.applyBindings(ViewModel, element);`

Comment: @KeithW. don't you have to do: `ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(), element);`?

Comment: try ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(), element);

Comment: @Alex that did it. Thanks

Comment: @DavidSherret Thanks

Comment: The code as currently posted doesn't reproduce the issue. It might be useful if OP edits the question to include the actual culprit from the comments, and either commenter or OP post the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter to ko.applyBindings should be the the object that represents the view model for Knockout. Since Knockout does not have any knowledge about typescript classes, you have to instantiate your class into the intended object before you send it into ko.applyBindings.

You could theoretically send in the class itself if you don't want to instantiate it, but then you'd have to define the properties of the class as static fields so that they end up directly on the object that gets passed in. Although I don't think there is any point in doing that.